# What is the error in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem when I execute this query:

```
SELECT 'preg', 'respA', 'respB', 'respC', 'respD', 'respV', 'subTema' 
FROM comun 
WHERE 'id' = 3
```

In the table id is of type INT.

PHPMyAdmin says that the query is correct but returns 0 rows and the table has 4 rows.
What is the error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you just call a query a "consultation"?

Comment: remove quotes, or use back ticks for field names

Comment: the problem was 'id'=3 if i write id = 3 it works

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks to escape column and table names, not quotes.

```
SELECT `preg`, ...
FROM `comun` 
WHERE `id` = 3
```

Quotes indicate a static string. And it returns zero rows because the static string `id` is not equal to `3`.

But actually you only need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).